# Multi Module Maven Project and Docker: Cannot find artifact?

Tags: java, docker, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have the following multi-stage `dockerfile` that attempts to copy each module of my multi-module `java maven` project and build my `ear` file using `mvn clean install`.

**dockerfile:**

```
# Copy files from local to maven image and build ear
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build  
COPY module1 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module2 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module3 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app  
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean install

# Create server image + rest of docker file (working ok)
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
Step 8/20 : RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean install
 ---> Running in cf9d8c1ef9ed
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.company.web:api:21.01-SNAPSHOT:
  Could not find artifact com.company.parent:jee6:pom:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT and
  'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
```

The section in the `pom.xml` that corresponds to this error:

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.company.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>jee6</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I assume this issue because when trying to run the command in the maven docker image it cannot see my local `.m2` folder? And the dependency that it is looking for is a private dependency on my local machine.

Would also copying my maven `settings.xml` help?

How can I resolve this? I do not want someone to have to have Maven installed on their machine in order to run this dockerfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependency `com.company.parent:jee6:pom:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT` seems to be private, your Maven command inside Docker build needs to be able to either download it from private repository or have it readily accessible.

> I assume this issue because when trying to run the command in the maven docker image it cannot see my local .m2 folder?

Yes, it then cannot see your `settings.xml` with private repository config, or local dependency if it's already available locally.

> Would also copying my maven settings.xml help?

It's better not to: your `settings.xml` (and eventual secrets within) may be available to anyone using your image later. Using a secret mount with BuildKit would be a better solution (see below)

---

You have multiple solutions:

## Mount `settings.xml` as secret during build

This solution assumes you have a `settings.xml` [configured with proper credentials to access private registry](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#servers).

Use [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) with [`--mount=secret`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#run---mounttypesecret) to load `settings.xml` as secret with a `Dockerfile` such as:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
# Required comment at top of Dockerfile for using BuildKit

FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build  

COPY module1 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module2 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module3 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app  

# Use your secret settings.xml
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mvnsettings,target=/root/.m2/settings.xml \
  mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean install
```

And build command such as:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=mvnsettings,src=$HOME/.m2/settings.xml .
```

Maven should then be able to download parent dependency during build.

*Note: this is NOT `COPY`ing the `settings.xml` in image, as the secret `settings.xml` will only be made available for the specified build step and won't be persisted in final image.*

## Copy `com.company.parent:jee6` `pom.xml` during build

This solution is less practical and may not solve problem entirely:

- It would require to have `com.company.parent:jee6:pom:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT` `pom.xml` file available in build context
- Your parent `pom.xml` may refer to other private dependencies. You would have to include them the same way.

... But it still may be worth a try.

You can do something like:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 AS build  

# Copy and install parent pom
COPY parent-pom.xml /tmp/parent/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /tmp/parent/pom.xml clean install

COPY module1 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module2 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY module3 /usr/src/app/src  
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app  
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different parts to the error: Cannot find the parent, and the parent.relativePath element is wrong.  I think the 2nd part might be causing the 1st.

Since your parent element doesn't specify a relativePath element, the default is the module parent path (aka ..). Your modules are not in a child of the parent folder (/usr/src/app) but rather in the (/usr/src/app/src subfolder).

Try changing your copy commands to :

```
COPY module1 /usr/src/app
COPY module2 /usr/src/app  
COPY module3 /usr/src/app  
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
```

You should then see:

```
/usr/src/app
/usr/src/app/module1
/usr/src/app/module2
/usr/src/app/module3
```

Comment: Sorry I am still getting the same error now